# Robinhood and W8BEN for Non-US residents

Tags: non-resident, robinhood

I have an account with Robinhood which I opened when I was in the US and never traded on the platform. I did some trades this year. I am now an Indian resident for the entire year and forgot to close the account before moving to India and unfortunately i didn't know that Robinhood was available only for US residents. It was a honest mistake and I am ready to pay any taxes or penalties applicable. I will close the account soon but want to know how to proceed to fix this mistake and can i send W8BEN form to Robinhood so they can withhold required amount if needed and i can file tax returns as non-resident next year. If i get 1099 next year can i still file my returns as 1040NR without claiming any tax exemptions?

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @ParshvaMehta I contacted a tax professional and he said Robinhood will issue a 1099 form and using that you can file 1040NR to report your capital gains and dividends and pay necessary tax

Comment: @prasad - Did you report your capital gains from 1099-B in Schedule NEC or 1040NR? As a non-resident, capital gains is not taxable in the US if reported in Schedule NEC but if we report on 1040NR, the capital gains is taxable. But Robinhood would have given a 1099 and also reported to IRS, what is the suggested approach?